# android layout dynamic width of listviews

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, width

in my layout i have 5 listviews next to each other, and a want them all together to match the screen size so that everyone of them has a width of 1/5 of the screens width. match parent doesnt work because then every listview is as big as the screen.

actually i use this:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="700dp"
                    android:id="@+id/listView2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="700dp"
                    android:id="@+id/listView3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="700dp"
                    android:id="@+id/listView4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="700dp"
                    android:id="@+id/listView5"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="700dp"
                    android:id="@+id/listView6"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

but that of course doesnt work for different screen sizes.

Comment: Its a sin to put `ListView` inside `ScrollView`!!! Seriously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't **EVER** put `ListView` inside `ScrollView`, anyways here is how you do it:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/listView2" />

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/listView3" />

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/listView4" />

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/listView5" />

        <ListView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/listView6" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why not? it works perfecly and it was the only way i found to scroll all listviews at the same time

Comment: To scroll them together you can see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342419/android-scrolling-2-listviews-together

Comment: And it is always good idea to Google if you are trying something unusual: https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+scroll+two+listviews&oq=scroll+two+listview&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.6692j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: i've already googled and i also found that but it looked a complicated and i thought it would be easier to use a scrollview. so could somebody explain no WHY thats not a good idea?

Comment: Its a very long answer, Why not watch this video before doing it http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html
In this video he explained many other things including putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. The short answer is `ListView` has its own scroll mechanism that makes sure to recycle views to avoid going into `OutOfMemory` error. I can see you have your `ListView`'s height equals to 700dp, have you thought what will happen if you `ListView` is longer than 700dp??

Comment: And what if your `ListView` rows are heavy ? You will eventually get out of memory as all the row `View`s will be initialized and `ListView` wont be able to use recycler.

Comment: my listviews get always filled with exactly 11 entries, that all have a maximum length of 2 lines, so they cant get longer than 700dp

Answer (score 0):

Put `android:weightSum="5"` to your `LinearLayout` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to your each ListView. You might need to set your width to 0.

I also wouldn't recommend putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView`.