# how to use parallel scrolling in android with two views

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, parallax

I am trying to use parallel scrolling in android.i.e.i have two view in a layout a `mapview` on the top and a `listview` in the bottom.when i scroll up in the `listview`, the mapview should also scrollup.as we keep scrolling the list should cover the whole screen.
 i have tried getting the cordinates of the listview using the `ViewTreeObserver.onGlobalLayoutListener`and

moving the listview on touch,which is not working out. can i get any suggestions on how to proceed.

`Edit:` I managed to get desired effect using `parallaxScrollview`. But how do i make the backGround image clickable in `parallaxscrollview`

Comment: You mean like expanding the map by pushing the ListView outside of the screen like Foursquare app or the new Maps app?

Comment: when the user scrolls up while scrolling the listview should take over the screen while the map goes out of the top edge of the screen.

Comment: I have tried using parallaxscrollview. but it takes scrollview as child how do i do it with a list view

Comment: Please lookout this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342419/android-scrolling-2-listviews-together

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to register for the onTouch of the listView and dynamically change the position and the size of the two components with every variation on the Y axis

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more...I am completely lost right now