# Android 3-List View (Lists scrolling together)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I want to build a view like the one of Sunrise in Android that shows three days on the screen. (http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/01/09/sunrise-calendar-goes-universal-confide-brings-off-the-record-messaging-to-apples-ios) (its the view in the middle).

I tried to use MergeAdapter (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) but couldn't get it to work. I also implemented the most popular solution of this post ([Android. Scrolling 2 listviews together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342419/android-scrolling-2-listviews-together)) extending it to 3 views instead of 2, but it was very clunky and slow.

Does anyone have a better suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not building a single ListView and arrange each list item like having 3 sections on 1 row if you already want to have them scrolling together? It wouldn't make sense to have 3 ListViews scrolling together.

Comment: So I need to be able to scroll to the right (while displaying multiple dates) and if it's only one single ListView the user would scroll 3 days at a time as opposed to one. So the three list Views need to be arranged as one list per page inside a ViewPager that lets you scroll one day at a time and to the right. (or left for that matter)