# Parallel listviews should scroll together when any one listview scrolls in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having two listviews in parallel on single screen. Both are having their own scroll listener.

What I want to do is scroll the first `listview`, then the second `listview` should also scroll and vice versa.

*Is this possible ?*

Comment: may be you can find out your answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342419/android-scrolling-2-listviews-together

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your ListViews are `mListView1` and `mListView2`, then do something like this -

```
  mListView1.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}                   

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            // Smooth scroll mListView2 according to mListView1.
            mListView2.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleItem);
        }

        @Override
        private void isScrollCompleted() {}
    });
```

Comment: But my both listviews having header. So in case when header is half visible for first listview, how to scroll another listview exactly at same place.

Comment: And if i use your without having header on listview, what if i scroll the first listview such that only half of any child is visible on top ?